# PhpStorm disable autocomplete or smart keys feature for Tab in CSS

Tags: css, autocomplete, tabs, phpstorm

When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after property name in rule body editor inserts `:;`

Affects versions: 2019.2, 2020.3

How can I disable this feature?
[image: before Tab]

[image: after Tab]

Comment: 1) Which "property name" exactly? Ideally a screenshot what what you see just before hitting the `Tab` key. 2) Try `Enter` instead -- any difference?

Comment: Screenshots added.On Enter - new line, nothing special. But on Backspace after Enter - its add Space after property name (its also not necessary in my case)

Comment: Right. That's the CSS property completion (if you press `Ctrl+Space` to the see Code Completion popup the entry will be with the `(p)` icon). It's a standard completion. The only difference is that I'm getting `font: [CARET];` -- a space in a different place (must be my Code Style setting for CSS). I'm not aware of any option that can have it disabled.

Comment: What is wrong with having `font: ;` ? It's correct syntax for CSS and I see nothing wrong with it: you will be writing those symbols anyway... or am I missing something?

Comment: Problem is, that i want option to disable this automation, if it exists, or enable, when i need it. Hard-coded automation its definitely not good! "Ctrl+Space" is ok, but with Tab i simply want to add aligning to values - on example, if this alignment already exists and i need follow it, but with this automation it's quite problematic.

Comment: Right. As far as I know -- such completion for CSS properties cannot be disabled. You may contact JetBrains Support if you need 100% official answer (use corresponding entry from the PhpStorm's Help menu).